# PowerShell Move-Item failing to move files

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to automate the move of photos from a drop folder into a managed folder, and I'm running the following script.

The problem is, It's not moving any of the files, and I'm not seeing any warnings. I have enabled the `-force` option, but it's still not moving anything. Powershell is set up to allow remote execution.

```
# Preq: Copy all files to $ImportPath`n

$ImportPath = "D:\Photo_Imports"
$JPGDest = "D:\Photos\ALL_PHOTOS\JPG"
$RAWDest = "D:\Photos\ALL_PHOTOS\RAW"
$MOVDest = "D:\Photos\ALL_PHOTOS\Movies"

Write-Host "About to run the script, hold on!" `n
Write-Host "File summary"
Get-Childitem $ImportPath -Recurse | where { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | group Extension -NoElement | sort count -desc 

# If $Path exists, get a list of all children (files/folders) and move each one to the $Dest folders
if(Test-Path $ImportPath)
{
    try
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Include *.JPG -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $JPGDest -Force
        Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Include *.CR2 -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $RAWDest -Force
        Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Include *.MOV -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $MOVDest -Force
    }
    catch
    {
        "Something broke, try manually"
    }
}
Write-Host `n
Write-Host " FINISHED ! " `n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx), the **-Include** parameter works only when the **-Recurse** is also specified.

So you need to add the **-Recurse** parameter, like so :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Include *.JPG -Recurse -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $JPGDest -Force
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Include *.CR2 -Recurse -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $RAWDest -Force
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Include *.MOV -Recurse -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $MOVDest -Force
```

Or, in case you don't want a recursive file search, don't use **-Recurse** and replace **-Include** with **-Filter**, like so :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Filter "*.JPG" -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $JPGDest -Force
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Filter "*.CR2" -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $RAWDest -Force
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath -Filter "*.MOV" -Verbose | Move-Item -Destination $MOVDest -Force
```

For non-recursive search, you could also do this :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath\*.JPG -Verbose
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath\*.CR2 -Verbose
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImportPath\*.MOV -Verbose
```